# Computer cannot remember I authorized it for my AppleID, no other device to authorize it from

Tags: itunes, apple-id, two-factor-authentication, authorization

My computer is a Lenovo IdeaPad S540, I'm using iTunes 12.11.3.7, and my computer is running on Windows 10 version 21H1.

I am trying to buy music on my iTunes, and my computer tells me it requires authorization to use my AppleID.  I have already authorized my computer at least twice, one of those times was in the last couple months.  It requires me to use a verification code sent to another device to authorize it, but I do not have another device that I can use to authorize it.  The problem is not just with iTunes though because in order to log in to my AppleID online I also need to do two factor authentication via a device that is already authorized.  I do not understand why Apple doesn't remember that my computer is authorized, and I do not know what to do without another computer to authorize mine from.

I also cannot view information about my account, since that also requires log in and authentication from an authorized device.

Comment: This sounds like a windows problem - not storing information.